# Master and Worker Clustering: On which core is the Master running?

Tags: node.js

On the [documentation-page](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) of Node.js clusters there are some examples where the workers are "spawned" like this:

```
  // Start workers and listen for messages containing notifyRequest
  const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
```

This means that for every CPU - core one worker is spawned, right?
On which CPU-Core is the master ? Node.js is single threaded so if there is only one master then there has to be 2 processes on at least one CPU - Core because the master has to run on one of the CPU-Cores. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: I am no expert but I don't think any program runs on a specific CPU-Core. I think its OS responsibility to divide and decide which core it will use each time.

Comment: Then I don't understand why i would write `for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++)` and spawn one worker for each cpu - core

Comment: Because if for some reason you app uses 100% of CPU all the time then if you have 4 cores with 4 threads you can run max 4 instances of your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you, for example, have 4 logical cores, a master node will be sharing a core with one of 4 workers, which isn't a big deal since the master node shouldn't handle any heavy load.

But here is a catch as [os.cpus](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_cpus) returns an amount of **logical cores**, not physical ones <s>it still should be fine if your application is I/O bound but for heavy computation tasks, you probably should consider limiting the number of workers to amount physical cores instead(or use another runtime).</s>

Comment: Hi G07cha, can you please explain that why we should consider limiting the number of workers to amount physical cores rather than logic cores? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @L_K, thanks for bringing it to my attention, I don't know what I was thinking in 2017 but this statement doesn't seem to be true. I haven't found any evidence that using all logical cores may be detrimental to performance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps taken from [How do multi core processors handle programs](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-3445342/multi-core-processors-handle-programs.html)

Check second paragraph. Its say about Single CPU programs like NodeJs.

> Each CPU Core has a pre-determined number of threads, for example, a
>   dual core CPU could potentially have 4 threads (Hyper-threading),
>   meaning that any given program running will use its assigned amount of
>   CPU resources on an assigned core. (Resource assignment is determined
>   primarily by the system itself, and whether or not the user, and
>   therefore the CPU has assigned resources to the workload). the CPU
>   threads, and cores, all run at the CPU's rated frequency, that is,
>   billion cycles per second. The faster the clock speed, the faster
>   processes are completed. A CPU with more cores can split its workload
>   more efficiently. For example, an 8 Core processor running at 1.5 Ghz
>   may indeed complete a process quicker, if the process is using all 8
>   cores at once. BUT, a single threaded program (A program using only
>   one thread), will take a much higher advantage of a CPU with say 2
>   cores running at 3 Ghz.
>
> If two programs are open that are programmed to use only 1 CPU Core,
>   the Program with the highest priority will be assigned to Core 0 (Core
>   zero is the first core). Any other programs that are open will be
>   assigned to the processor core that will complete the process
>   quickest. More often than not, the computers operating system will
>   work relatively well to split workloads across multiple cores,
>   unfortunately, some programs are only programmed to take advantage of
>   one core. If this is the case, the program likely does not need
>   multiple cores, unlike a video editing program or 3D development
>   program.
>
> If 8 programs were open at once, and if they were all using a
>   considerable amount of CPU resources, on a 4 core CPU, for 1, the
>   computer would be noticeably slower than if it were idle. Each process
>   will be given an assigned amount of CPU resources, and each program
>   would be prioritised accordingly, and instructions would be stored in
>   the CPU's cache, but if the programs open are using 100% of the CPU's
>   usage, and is running at its maximum frequency, then the programs will
>   slow down, as they will be held in a 'queue' and a considerable delay
>   would be implied until the CPU has completed its instructions. Note, a
>   similar effect can be witnessed when downloading files; 8 simultaneous
>   downloads will download slower than 2, if the files are reaching the
>   download speed limit.
>
> Hope this helps, and as a general rule of thumb, for basic
>   applications, CPU Speed is more important than core count, although
>   generally speaking, a CPU with 2 or more cores is pretty good for
>   general use.